# Magento - Beginner Concepts - Theme structure

Tags: php, html, css, magento, e-commerce

I am a beginner with Magento trying to build a simple custom theme and while I have done a fair bit of research I am really in need of some simple clarifications because I think that the learning curve is rather steep but worth it once some basic concepts are understood. My design goals are very basic: All products listed on the homepage with different image sizes, floating left.

What I've done is downloaded the 'Modern' theme as a base to work with and renamed it:

```
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme
skin/frontend/default/mytheme
```

I've done some basic tweaking to the phtml files in

```
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/
```

However, I have a number of questions:

1. Where exactly is the template for the homepage? Is it only customizable using the CMS>Pages control in the backend under Design>Page Layout? This confuses me because I am used to developing in wordpress and creating a custom php file for the index/homepage. I really think this separation of html/xml is really the hard thing for me to grasp.
2. If i can only customize the homepage using the backend, I see the block: `<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">`. Navigating to mytheme directory, I don't see anything referring to this. Where are these things located? Am I supposed to copy any file missing from mytheme from the base?
3. Is it only possible to have 1 column, 2 column, 3 column etc. layouts?

An endless thanks to anyone who can steer me in the right direction. I really think it is just a matter of understanding very important fundamentals of how Magento themes are structured. At the moment I am already finding it so frustrating having my finder window open 7 folders deep and having to move around constantly. How I miss the simplicity of Wordpress' single folder themes.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read all things in http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base before you go further

1. homepage content can be anything you want and you can reference it to be anything with layout file descriptors
2. MVC concept tells that it is taken from catalog/product_new block and from whatever is set to it's template. In current case catalog/product/new.phtml is used and you can edit this
3. you can have a completely custom setup and not restricted to anything that default contains. However it is wise to use defaults as almost all extensions depend on defaults more or less.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at the Magento knowledge base under 'Themes and Design' and find that all the articles seem to be introductions with no depth/link to the full content? (www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/designing-your-store). Regardless, I've read through in great depth, the design guide at http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/ and now I understand the concepts of blocks, layouts and templates but am still at a complete loss for how to edit specifically, the blocks to display on the homepage itself. I am struggling to see the fundamental basic connection.

Comment: Very simply put, if I want to list all the products on my homepage, which files do I need to edit? Currently, even with the Layout Update XML in the CMS, nothing is displaying on the homepage. I know I am missing something incredibly basic, but once I understand it I really think I will be able to move quickly. It's really this fundamental starting block I can't seem to find the answer to myself.

Comment: you are missing the knowledge and understanding how magento layout works :) the idea is that whole structure is defined in layout files and you can reference each block or layout handle with other layout descriptions. This is very abstract system and easy to be mistaken in. So basically you can take the catalog/product_new as example

Answer (score 0):

A very big part of magento design is layouts.
whether you choose to use a local.xml or change files from layouts folder you must have an ideea on how they work.

Here is a link for start

[Intro to Layouts](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)

There are many others resources outhere ofcourse.